# mock response.elapsed in requests_mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, response, requests-mock

I'm using requests_mock in my unit tests and would like to mock response.elapsed attribute but have't found proper way to do it. Just found a workaround with adding sleep to text callback.

```
with requests_mock.mock() as m:
    def text_callback_with_delay(request, context):
        time.sleep(2)
        return "{}"

    m.get(GET_REQUEST_URL, text=text_callback_with_delay)
```

Is there a better way to mock **response.elapsed** using **requests_mock**?

Comment: Do you want to mock the elapsed attribute of the returned response object or do you want the mocked request to take 2 seconds?

Comment: I need to mock the elapsed attribute of the returned response object. With example given above response.elapsed is bit more than 2 seconds. So I just used unittest.mock.patch to patch requests.request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With example given above response.elapsed is bit more than 2 seconds. So I just used **unittest.mock.patch** to patch **requests.request**

```
mock_response = Mock(spec=requests.Response)
mock_response.elapsed = datetime.timedelta(seconds=2.0)

with patch("requests.request", return_value=mock_response):
     my_code_here
```

Comment: this approach is not using `requests_mock` as asked